# alternatives to the "PGP pathfinder"

Tags: pgp, openpgp

The author of the [PGP pathfinder](https://pgp.cs.uu.nl/) [deceased](https://www.apache.org/memorials/henk_penning.html) this year. Shortly after the data was not updated any more.

Are there any alternatives known to [find signature paths](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/108664/218636)?

Comment: @yosl: You asked why this question is off-topic. StackExchange wants to be a questions/answers site. That's why the questions should be of such kind, that they are relevant also long time after they were asked. But product recommendations become obsolete quickly. Such answers become irrelevant or incorrect very soon, which is not the goal of SE.

Answer (score 0):

The program used to calculate it is public: https://pgp.cs.uu.nl/wotsap/

As is the archive data it uses, updated as of... today https://pgp.cs.uu.nl/archive/wot-0.3/

Comment: There was [a debian package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/wotsap) maintained by  for wotsap until 2020, but as far as I can see, nobody is hosting the web app now and nobody is creating the `wot` file dumps.  Also this version of "wotsap" which claims to be written by someone else: Copyright 2003,2004 Jörgen Cederlöf. Also not maintained.